# Is there anyway of returning the options of a GoogleChart after the chart has been edited using the ChartEditor class?

Tags: google-visualization

I want to store the configuration of multiple GoogleCharts in a database and use them to create a dashboard of charts.

I currently store the options I supply for each chart in the database and have my dashboard working, displaying multiple charts.

I want to use the ChartEditor class to allow a user to amend a chart and then save the changes back to my database, so that the next time the dashboard is created, the changes are persisted.

Hence, when a user clicks on the OK button on the ChartEditor dialog, is there a way of accessing the changes to these options?

Answer (score 1):

After crawling around, inspecting the ChartEditor object....

```
$.parseJSON(chartEditor.getChartSpecification())['options']
```

...returns what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Flippsie's answer, you can recreate the saved chart from the json returned from chartEditor.getChartSpecification()

```
  var json = chartEditor.getChartSpecification(); // Or saved JSON value
  var spec = JSON.parse(json);

  // Get the chart details from the saved spec
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(spec.dataTable);
  var options = spec.options;
  var chartType = spec.chartType || "BarChart";
  
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  window.chart = new google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
```